# SQL Stored Procedure : Incorrect syntax within imbricated IFs

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I get "Incorrect syntax" errors on every nested IF and ELSE statements in the following code... what's wrong ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WTFAULT].[usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus]
(
@linxPartId int = -1,
@faultStatus varchar(10) output
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NbFaultsInParts int,
            @NbPartsReturned int

    SET @NbPartsReturned = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID 
                                AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'ALLOCATED')

    IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
            SET @faultStatus = 'ALLOCATED'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
            SET @NbPartsReturned = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID 
                                        AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'DRAFT')

            IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
                    SET @faultStatus = 'DRAFT'
            END
            ELSE BEGIN
                SET @NbPartsReturned = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID 
                                            AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'CLOSED')
                IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
                        SET @faultStatus = 'CLOSED'
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                        SET @faultStatus = ''
                END
            END
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: You haven't specified what DBMS, though I'm sure those who know it will recognise the syntax.  Also, what does "imbricated" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this different method:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WTFAULT].[usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus](@linxPartId int = -1,
@faultStatus varchar(10) output)
AS   

SELECT COUNT(*) as MaturityCount,WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY  INTO #Temp
FROM WTFAULT.PART JOIN WTFAULT.FAULT 
    ON WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID 
WHERE TFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId 
GROUP BY WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY

If (select MaturityCount from #temp where WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'ALLOCATED') >0
    BEGIN
        SET @faultStatus = 'ALLOCATED'
    END
ELSE IF
(select MaturityCount from #temp where WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'DRAFT') >0
    BEGIN
        SET @faultStatus = 'DRAFT'
    END
ELSE IF
(select MaturityCount from #temp where WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'CLOSED') >0
    BEGIN
        SET @faultStatus = 'CLOSED'  
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN                                        
        SET @faultStatus = ''                        
    END
```

I also changed your query to use ANSI standard joins. You should use them too from now on. They are clearer, easier to maintain and will not give wrong results when you use outer joins  and are far less likely to result in a cross join by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @faultStatus nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @NbFaultsInParts int
DECLARE @NbPartsReturned int

SELECT @NbPartsReturned = COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'ALLOCATED'

IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
                SET @faultStatus = 'ALLOCATED'
END
ELSE BEGIN
                SELECT @NbPartsReturned = COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID  AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'DRAFT'

                IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
                                SET @faultStatus = 'DRAFT'
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                        SELECT @NbPartsReturned = COUNT(*) FROM WTFAULT.PART, WTFAULT.FAULT WHERE WTFAULT.PART.FAULT_COID = WTFAULT.FAULT.COID  AND WTFAULT.PART.LINX_PARTID = @linxPartId AND WTFAULT.FAULT.MATURITY = 'CLOSED'

                        IF @NbPartsReturned > 0 BEGIN
                                        SET @faultStatus = 'CLOSED'
                        END
                        ELSE BEGIN
                                        SET @faultStatus = ''
                        END
                END
        END
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not putting your `begins` and `ends` on the same lines as other statements.

Also, just as an unrelated tip, try using statements like "`select @NbPartsReturned = count(*) from WTFAULT.PART...`" rather than "`set @NbPartsReturned = (select count(*) from WTFAULT.PART...`", as you'll turn two statements into one.

If this doesn't take care of your problem, try putting up the text of the entire error.

Answer (score 0):

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus, Line 25

Incorrect syntax near ' '.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus, Line 29

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus, Line 33

Incorrect syntax near ' '.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_WTFault_GetPartFaultStatus, Line 37

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.